# Performance issue of QGraphicsView framework when trying to draw 2000*2000 ellipse

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Just start to play with Qt graphics. I plan to have a project that is able to visualize a network of hundreds of thousands of nodes, and millions of connections between them.

When handling `QGraphicsScene` with up to thousands of `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, scaling `QGraphicsView` is quite smooth by `QGraphicsView::setMatrix()`. But it gets much worse when I draw millions of ellipses in the scene, especially when I zoomed out to show all of them in the view. However, according to the "4000 chips" example in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html, Qt should be able to deal with large number of items nicely.

Is there any way to alleviate the slowness issue, and possibly reducing memory consumption at the same time? I checked many other examples, search quite a lot, but couldn't find any similar case.

Comment: implement LOD (level of detail) logic

Comment: I had similar problems when drawing millions of lines in QGraphicsScene. I did not find any good way to optimize drawing. I was able to create very fast algorithm for creation of the line path, but then drawing took a long time after it.